# How to get data from sql DB to specific part of html page

Tags: html, node.js, function

So i am very new to Node JS / Express / SQL so if i am posting something that is silly I apologize ..... End goal here is data I am extracting from my DB I want to see it on a particular field on my html page where the request was invoked.

High-level .. I have a HTML page with a button called lookup. When i click that button it reaches out to my DB, it connects and then pulls down the table info and redirects me to a blank page with all of the info.

So again .. What i want to do is the data that is pulled down I want to place that on to a particular place (field) on the current html page.

app.js (snippet for this get only)

```
app.get('/lookup', function (req, res) {
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
    var request = new sql.Request();
    if (err) throw err;
    request.query('select * from MYTABLE', function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    res.send(result);
    console.log("Connected");
    });
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use techniques like [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) to request data.

```
button.onclick = () => {
    fetch('/lookup').then((data) => {
        input.value = data
    })
}
```

Element selectors(button, input) are not shown as the core part is requesting data asynchronously. It actually, has little to do with the backend part. You shall use frontend JavaScript to display data appropriately.

Comment: Yes but this does not help me ... I know it should probably be an ajax call.